# Is aluminium hydroxide a strong base?

Tags: acid-base

Is $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ in a very dilute solution deemed as a strong base? Are there any actual experimental data for it?

Comment: $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ is all but insoluble in water (though you may call that _"a very dilute solution"_, if you like), and most certainly is not a strong base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not a strong base.

It is a weak acid with pKa of 5

See [DISSOCIATION CONSTANTS OF INORGANIC ACIDS AND BASES IN AQUEOUS SOLUTION](http://pac.iupac.org/publications/pac/pdf/1969/pdf/2002x0133.pdf) at the page numbered 143 (page 12 of the file).